# Docker MySQL connectivity issues on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I am having difficulty to connect to a docker container instance of MySql running on Ubuntu.  Here is the code that creates the docker:

```
docker run --name=mysql_db --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -p 3308:3308 -v /opt/permstorage:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:latest
```

I have been trying to diagnose access from another Ubuntu machine in my network but I keep getting connection refused.  I can login to the docker using the command below so I know my password is correct.

```
docker exec -it mysql_db mysql -uusername -p
```

I have successfully run the exact same code using an AWS server, but for some reason its not working in my network, and I suspect it has to do with ip addresses, but it's beyond my capacity to diagnose how to solve this.

I have opened the 3308 port in ufw.  But I cannot access the docker mysql instance even using dbeaver locally.  Where should I start to diagnose this?  Adding addition info below:

```
(base) user@Alienware:~/Downloads$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3308
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
(base) user@Alienware:~/Downloads$ telnet 192.168.4.249 3308
Trying 192.168.4.249...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
(base) user@Alienware:~/Downloads$ telnet localhost 3308
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
(base) user@Alienware:~/Downloads$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for user: 
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3389/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3389                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3308                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3389/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3389 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3308 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my fault was mapping the internal port to 3308 as well.  The following corrected my issue:

```
docker run --name=mysql_db --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -p 3308:3306 -v /opt/permstorage:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:latest
```